# Tag badge styling issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The styling for the tag badges does not fit with the rest of the design.

[image: Odd tag styling]

Comment: I'm fixing this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.

Comment: When is the next deployment? This was closed 2 weeks ago, but I see the problem is still the same...

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto This was deployed. where are you seeing the problem still? Please link me a url.

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1375/matt-grum

Comment: @Pearson tag badges are supposed to look differently from the regular badges. This is by design though.